# Force a Plan Guide in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query embedded in an application which I cannot access to change without contacting the original developers and getting them to change it.

The query that I am trying to alter is very slow to run and yields incomplete data, I have an improved version of this query and am looking for a way in SQL Server 2008 to essentially substitute the original query with the improved one when the original query is run through the application.

I have tried to create and force a Plan Guide based on the original query to force the new query. Following this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190772(v=sql.105) (as well as others).

So far every attempt to use plan forcing seems to have failed and the original query still gets executed. Does anyone know if I'm taking the right approach here? Or is there a better solution to the problem that I've described.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to substitute one query for another in this manner.

Comment: This is not possible. You can substitute new query plans for queries, but those plans are still required to logically yield the same results as the original query. (There's probably some obscure wiggle room here if nondeterminism is introduced, but materially changing the result set is right out.) The only fix for a query that's flat-out incorrect (not merely slow) is to correct the query.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is not possible. If you can get the developers to change the query in the app, ask them to call a stored procedure. That way you can update the proc whenever you need to - it gives you much more flexibility in how the query operates and what it does.